# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider - 6.5.5.0 MySQL files + GoDaddy

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, mysql-connector

I know this question has been answered multiple times, still none of the answers seems to have fixed my problem.

Here are some details about my application,

- MySQL version in GoDaddy - 5.0.
- Connector versions in my GAC,

  - MySQL.Data 5.0.9.0
  - MySQL.Web 6.6.5.0
  - MySQL.Data.CF 6.7.4.0
- Connector versions that I have bin deployed,

  - MySQL.Data 6.6.5.0
  - MySQL.Web 6.6.5.0
  - MYSQL.Data.Entity 6.6.5.0
    (I got these version from \ProgramFiles\MYSQL\Connector NET..)
- Entity Framework 5.0/4.0 (tried both, still no luck!)
- ASP .NET MVC 4

And my configuration looks like this,

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
           invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BlogEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.BlogEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.BlogEntities.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=somehost;User id=someuser;pwd=somepassword;database=somedb&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Stack trace that I get,

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
>   providerInvariantName) +1426271
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString) +27
>
> [ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in
>   the configuration, or is not valid.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString) +92
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String
>   newConnectionString) +246
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +43
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String
>   connectionString) +85
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString,
>   String defaultContainerName) +16    Foo.Models.BlogEntities..ctor() in
>   BlogEntities.Designer.cs:34

Here are some stuffs which I already tried. 
- In the DbProviderFactories, I tried giving the complete name of the bin deployed assembly (version and the public keytoken). 
- I tried placing different versions of MySQL*.dll to the bin folder and deployed. 
- I have tried both versions of Entity Framework (4.0 as well as 5.0).

NOTE - I have removed all the other sections like DefaultProfileProvider, DefaultMembershipProvider, DefaultRoleProvider, DefaultSessionProvider that uses DefaultConnection (as I have removed DefaultConnection as well).. 
It works fine in the local machine but fails when hosted in GoDaddy server.

**you can find the complete configuration file @ https://gist.github.com/sudarsanyes/6149579**

Still no luck. Please help! This is driving me crazy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed all of these issues. Here is what I did,

1. Migrated to the latest EF v6.0.
2. Download the latest MySql EF connectors 6.8.3 thru' nuget.
3. Running the application in Full trust.

   <system.web>
       <trust level="Full" />
     </system.web>

Now things seems to be working as excepted.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by replacing "User id" with "UID" in connection string...